# Не выполняется действие после цикла

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Цикл для обнаружения элемента. Потом, когда кнопка пропадает, нужно просто выполнить другие действия и т.д. Но сейчас, неправильно написано, не знаю как выполнить, подскажите пожалуйста:

```
        if ((games.MoreGames.Displayed)==false)

        {
            int i = 6;
            while (i > 0)
            {

                games.MoreGames.Click();
            }

        }


        else if (games.MoreGames.Displayed)
        {

            games.MoveCursorToGame(games.BookOfRaImage);
            games.GamePlayButton.Click();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(6000);

            var balance = games.BalanceTextPartners.Text.DoubleParseAdvanced();



            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(DELAY);
            games.ButtonClick(games.GameContainer, 693, 750);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            games.ButtonClick(games.GameContainer, 693, 750);
            //games.BalanceTextPartners.Click();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Assert.AreNotEqual(balance, games.BalanceTextPartners.Text.DoubleParseAdvanced());
        }
```

Comment: В вашем коде нет действий после цикла

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а как к вашему вопросу и коду относится `selenium`? Я у вас в коде только одну функцию нашёл связанную с ним - `.Click()`. Я говорю про то, что нужно указывать теги, которые передают смысл вашего вопроса (проблемы), так люди могут ориентироваться, что-бы помочь в той сфере, которую они знают лучше.

Comment: @AtachiShadow простите, но теги указанны. Ну я уже все решыл. Спасибо

Comment: @Strend я о том, что Ваша проблема относится к синтаксису кода, то есть, тег `C#` - то что нужно. А вот теги `selenium` и `selenium-webdriver` только вводят в заблуждение. Старайтесь максимально точно описывать проблему словами, кодом и тегами. Так вам помогут быстрее и точнее. Я, к примеру, не разбираюсь в `C#`, но чаще всего, при решении проблем с `selenium'ом`, это не мешает. А в вашем варианте наоборот, проблема в самом коде на `C#`, а не в `selenium`. И я понимаю, что русский может быть не родным для вас языком))))) но **-жи- -ши-** пишутся в русском языке с буквой **-и-** - "реш**и**л".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас должен быть декремент переменной i, и желательно показать весь код с action-ами, а то непонятно что делает метод - games.MoreGames.Click();